# Is there any way to view entire contents of variable in Python IDLE Debugger?

Tags: debugging, python-idle

I am trying to view the *entire* contents of a variable in the IDLE Debugger for Python 3.6.1. The debugger gives a preview but there appears to be no way to pull all the data out from the debugger.

The only work-around I've found is to throw a `print()` statement in the code somewhere. Is this the only way? See picture:
[image]

This example's `decryptedText` variable has over 700 characters but as we see, only a few are visible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As the IDLE debugger is currently written, the only way to get more information about the state of an object at a particular point in the execution is to either insert `print` calls in the code or stop execution (`raise SystemExit`, for instance) and interact with the object in the Shell.

What you see in the locals/globals panels are representations of objects produced by `reprlib.Repr` with `maxstring` and `maxother` increased to `60`.  One could edit `NamespaceViewer` in `idlelib/debugger.py` (3.6 name) to increase `maxstring` to, say, 200 and maximize the debug window.  (I verified that this works to show more of a string.)  One could also try replacing the single line Entry widget with a Label widget sized to `height` lines and `width` chars and setting `maxstring` to `height * width`.  (Untried.)

I agree that being able to get more information on a object would be good.  I am currently thinking about a separate popup window with type, length (if appropriate), and a much bigger slice of the contents.